# Configure trac for anonymous ticket submissions

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking, trac, configure

How would one configure trac to allow anonymous submission of tickets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your trac config you need to give the anonymous user the TICKET_CREATE permission.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Admin > Permissions, then give "anonymous" the TICKET_CREATE and TICKET_MODIFY privileges (actions).

See: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions

Answer (score 3):

Setup a trac site to allow anonymous (no actual login) login. Grant the anonymous user permission to only create tickets, and maybe view existing tickets if you wish. But deny all other permissions.

The trac admin plugin makes this pretty easy.